# How can i do conditional formatting in datgridview in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**In windows Application**
I want to Set colors of different cells in datagridview based on the value range

Suppose
value 1..22 : cell color should be green
value 23.30 : cell color should be gray
value >30 : cell color should be red

how can i do it..please suggest some code snippet?
How can i do conditional formatting in datgridview in C#?

Comment: Please also look at this answer that uses CellOnFormat http://stackoverflow.com/a/4067612/581414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply DataGridViewCellStyle object based on different condition

```
DataGridViewCellStyle cellstyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
cellstyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
cellstyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
dgvAllData.Rows[5].Cells[2].Style = cellstyle;
dgvAllData.Rows[3].Cells[2].Style = cellstyle;
dgvAllData.Rows[6].Cells[2].Style = cellstyle;
```

Answer (score 1):

See my answer for [Windowsforms: How to draw lines/bars on a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118116/windowsforms-how-to-draw-lines-bars-on-a-datagridview/1118164#1118164). The question provides an answer in VB.NET (should be easy enough to convert to C#).

**Updated to suit question**

Example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value > 0 && e.Value <= 22 )
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Color.Green, e.CellBounds);
    }
    else if (e.Value > 22 && e.Value <= 30 )
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Color.Grey, e.CellBounds);
    }
    else if (e.Value > 30)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Color.Red, e.CellBounds);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Color.White, e.CellBounds);
    }
}
```